# Impossible to login when launched from other app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, login

The only way to login I know of is using the menu button under the Feed title. When the app is launched by a third party, this menu has been replaced by a back button. That means there is no apparent way to login as the user is only presented with a sign-up form when attempting any action requiring an account.

**1. Opening Stack Exchange from a browser link**

> [image: step 1]

**2. App running - ready for user action**

> [image: step 2]

**After pressing upvote or similar - only sign-up action possible**

> [image: sign up prompt]

**Where do I click to login?**

> [image: sign up screen]

Comment: No idea what you mean. Screenshots might help. (also, what you mean "launched by third party"? The only way I know to launch apps in my device is tapping the icon of the app I want to launch.)

Comment: The menu is also accessible by swiping the left screen to the right (similar to Google's apps), unless I'm missing something. Meanwhile, what is the device model? AFAIK, phone layout and tablet layout has some differences (I only have phone, so I don't know about the tablet)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'll add some screenshots in a jiffy..

Comment: @AndrewT. That is true, but I didn't know (or forgot - I am using those gestures in other apps), and I am assuming other users might not either. I am using an Xperia Z2, btw. I think the main problem is that when trying to do any action as a non-logged user the only option you are presented with is sign-up, not sign-in.

Comment: added screenshots

Comment: the point is not that it is _possible_ to sign in, but that an unassuming user has no way of knowing it when given the presented options.

Comment: Weren't you logged in already?

Comment: So the bug is just wording? You want it to be "Sign in" instead of "Sign up"? I thought you mean you can't log in.

Comment: No, just changing words would not fix anything, as you can see from the screenshots. You are still just presented with sign-up screens where it is not possible to login. Either provide a sign-in option at the sign-up screen or change the wording and flow.

@PatrickHofman: no I was not logged in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.0.85.

There'll be three specific improvements:

1. Instead of having a "Sign Up" button, it will read "Log in or register".
2. Tapping the link will take you to the splash page with "Sign up" and "Log in" links.  You can go to either, tap back, then switch to the other.
3. If you try to sign up with an existing account, you'll now get a friendlier error: "You already have a Stack Exchange account with this email address. Would you like to log in instead?"  Tapping "Log in" will use the Google or Facebook credentials you just passed in and use them to log you into your existing account.

Answer (score 1):

I check this with `Android Opera` and with `UCBrowser`

And i understood about your bugs, And ***i tested own***

When i **logout** the browser and log back(`Opera`), and click on **vote up**

then it shows

[image: image 1]

and then I click ***login or register***

[image: image 2]

### In here ***No Sign Up Option***

and the i log with stack app

[image: image 03]

if i click **sign up**,

### as you mention there is no option call ***Sign In***

and i click on my login

then its shows

[image: 04]

***E-Mail in use***

> So till fix the error **there is only one option to before visit to site**. That is When you launch Stack app,

[image: 05]

You have to pick ***Sign-Up*** or ***Sign-In***

Comment: Thanks for checking in. FYI I _did_ manage to log in by opening the app separately later on, but thought it should be reported anyhow.