# Stack Exchange Mobile App - No Login Option

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

I might just be really dense, but I'm not sure how to login from the Stack Exchange Mobile App, on Android.  On my phone I googled "LINQPad for Java", and clicked on a link that took me to this page:

[Is there any program like LINQPad for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855077/is-there-any-program-like-linqpad-for-java)

So I decided I wanted to upvote one of the posts.  When I clicked on upvote, I was presented with a dialog asking if I wanted to "Cancel" or "Sign Up".   Erm... neither!  I want to login, because I already have an account.

[image: SE Login Prompt]

Why is there no "Login" option here?  What am I missing?

Comment: What happens if you hit Sign Up?

Comment: I tried that.  I am presented with option "Sign up using Google" or "Sign up using Stack Exchange".  When I click option "Sign up using Google", it says "Email address already in use", and I'm back at square one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.0.85 as described in [Impossible to login when launched from other app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266920/impossible-to-login-when-launched-from-other-app)

In the mean time, if you swipe from the left edge of the screen you should get a menu with an option to "Sign up or log in" at the top.